# Facebook friend invite code

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a javascript function to invite facebook user's to my "app" which is my website where you can login using facebook. When the user clicks invite friends, the invite friends dialog pops up, you can invite your friends and all is fine. When the friends who got invited go to their facebook, they get the notification to come use the app. However, when they click the notification it says this (for me cause im the developer).

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/5708/screencapturezk.jpg

I want it to actually take me to the page where the user has to allow the app permission like so :

http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4337/screencapture1v.jpg

I know it's not the javascript... It has to be an app setting. I don't understand the canvas url part. I've looked into it, and it looks like you only use that when you have an app that operates through facebook, but from your website. That's not what I want. Any help please? It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

The error message should have pointed you to the right place I think, it's saying that you haven't specified your canvas URL and secure canvas URL - these settings are configured under 'App on Facebook.com' in the app settings.

Invites go to your the root of your Canvas App (i.e apps.facebook.com/something - which maps to the 'canvas url' and 'secure canvas url' fields in the settings ) - if you need to redirect them somewhere else after processing the Request, you've to implement that yourself

Comment: What would my canvas url be? the url to my page. And do I need one even if my "app" is really an external site?

Comment: Assuming you have an app namespace of 'yourapp', you conmfigure the canvas URL and secure canvas URL to be somewhere on your server - whichever page you want users to end up on when they go to apps.facebook.com/yourapp - it will be wrapped with Facebook's chrome.
You don't need one in general, but you do if you're planning to use Requests - as these always bring the user to the app's canvas page - there's no reason you can't immediately redirect to http://yoursite.com/ once you process the request though

Comment: Thank you! I can't figure out though how it would bring you directly to the app's "request permission" page. Instead it's just loading my page in the canvas. That Thinkdiff app I showed in the screen shot goes straight to the app's request permission's page. When you hit approve, it brings you right back to the app.